# How to programmatically create and assign variables inside an R function

Tags: r

I am trying to download datasets from Quandl, assign my own newly created names to the dataframes I create in the function and then save them as R.data files to be loaded back into the global environment in later sessions.

The problem I'm having is in saving the R.data file in such a way that when I reload the file it has the variable name that I want for the dataframe.

So for example I tried the following function:

```
retrieve_FRED_data <-
  function(dataID = Quandl_FRED_Identifier, filename = assigned_name) {
    require(Quandl)
    Quandl.api_key("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    data <- Quandl(paste(c("FRED/", dataID), collapse = ""))
    assign(filename, data)
    save(filename, file = paste(c(filename, ".Rdata"), collapse = ""))
    return(filename)
  }
```

This worked to a point.  I could now get a dataframe object in my functions environment that was a copy of 'data' but with the correct 'assigned_name'.

But the save function doesn't work as intended.  All I've done is saved a character string variable that has the same name as the character string, not the dataframe that I had intended.

I've tried to modify the 'filename' argument within the save function by using 'as.name(filename)', various attempts at using the substitute function, using eval in front of substitute, etc. etc.

Each time I try something like this I get an error that says "as.name(filename) object not found", and similar for the other attempts.

How can I pass my 'filename = assigned_name' function argument as an argument into the save function?

UPDATE:

Sorry everyone, I didn't play close enough attention to Ruis' modified edit. And thanks to Aaron too, since also figured it out.  The following code works perfectly:

```
retrieve_FRED_data_mod <-
  function(dataID = Quandl_FRED_Identifier, filename = assigned_name) {
    require(Quandl)
    Quandl.api_key("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    data <- Quandl(paste(c("FRED/", dataID), collapse = ""))
    assign(filename, data)
    save(list = filename, file = paste0(filename, ".RData"))
    return(get(filename))
  }
```

Comment: After now reading your code again, try just `list=filename` in your call to `save.` The help page for save explains it... if you already understand the difference between symbols, character strings, and names, that is! :)

Comment: Hi JAW, glad something worked for you. Please pick the answer that worked for you and check it, so others know it has been answered.

Comment: Also, this usage of `require` is not really appropriate, in this case `library` is better, and it really should be at the beginning of script, not in the function. This is because `require` does not fail, it will only cause a warning, and if you need to install the package, you want it to fail right away. (And yes, the naming can be considered misleading, but that's what it is...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I've commented out the `Quandl` related stuff just to test the `save` part of the code. So one of the arguments passed on to the function is a dummy argument. For your real use case remove the comment characters and it will do what you need. A file is created in the working directory and the test dataset `data` is saved under the argument `Quandl_FRED_identifier = "x"` and returned by the function.

```
retrieve_FRED_data <-
  function(dataID = Quandl_FRED_Identifier, filename = assigned_name) {
#    require(Quandl)
#    Quandl.api_key("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
#    data <- Quandl(paste(c("FRED/", dataID), collapse = ""))
    assign(dataID, data)
    save(list = dataID, file = paste0(filename, ".Rdata"))
    return(get(dataID))
  }

data <- data.frame(X = 1:5, Y = 6:10)
Quandl_FRED_Identifier <- "x"  # name of the object (df) to be saved
assigned_name <- "so"    # so = stackoverflow, obviously
retrieve_FRED_data(Quandl_FRED_Identifier, assigned_name)
#  X  Y
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10
```

Note also that you can use `paste0(filename, ".RData")` which is simpler but I haven't changed that part, I only did the changes strictly needed to make the function save the file.

**EDIT.**
There was a missing argument `list` to `save`. It seems to be working correctly now.

```
x
#  X  Y
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10
rm(x)
load("so.RData")
x
#  X  Y
#1 1  6
#2 2  7
#3 3  8
#4 4  9
#5 5 10
```

**EDIT 2.**
The function is creating files with objects named according to the argument passed to it. Considering the mess in the comments, I will repeat part of the code above, namely, the first call to the function. It will create a file `so.RData` with a df named `x`. The second call creates a file `so2.RData` with df `y`. Then, I remove *both* `x` and `y`. When the files are `load`ed the df's are in the `globalenv` as expected.

```
data <- data.frame(X = 1:5, Y = 6:10)
Quandl_FRED_Identifier <- "x"  # 
assigned_name <- "so"    # so = stackoverflow, obviously
retrieve_FRED_data(Quandl_FRED_Identifier, assigned_name)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(5), B = rnorm(5))
Quandl_FRED_Identifier <- "y"  # 
assigned_name <- "so2"    # so = stackoverflow, obviously
retrieve_FRED_data(Quandl_FRED_Identifier, assigned_name)

rm(x, y)

load("so.RData")
load("so2.RData")

x
y
```

Comment: Well, yes, I was able to get this far too, but it doesn't solve my problem.  The issue becomes the name assigned to the dataframe when it's reloaded back into the workspace.  In this case it will always be named 'data'.  It doesn't take on the variable name 'so'.  This doesn't work for me because I need to download several different data sets and assign different names to them and reload the whole group back into my workspace, each with their different assigned name.

Comment: @JAW So what is not working? The file is saved with the data frame, wasn't that the issue?

Comment: Yes, it saves the file and the FILE NAME is correct, but the dataframe variable name is not the assigned name when I reload it.  I can reload it using the correct filename, but the variable name assigned to the dataframe is 'data', not 'so'.

Comment: So when I try to reload multiple data files, each with a unique file name, they will all end up overwriting the same dataframe variable named 'data' and I'll end up with only one dataframe named 'data', which will be the last one to be loaded.

Comment: The reason for the `assign` was my attempt to copy the original `data` object and give it the correct `assigned_name`.  This worked, and I got the desired variable name for the dataframe object, but I can't figure out a way to save it with that name.

Comment: OK, sorry, and thanks for trying to help, but I'm afraid you're missing the point.

Comment: The problem isn't the filename.  That part is working perfectly.  The problem is the variable name assigned to the dataframe when it gets reloaded.  So in this case, when I reload the file called `so.Rdata` it finds the file with that name and reloads the correct data, but it assigns the variable name `data` to the loaded dataframe.  This doesn't solve my problem because no matter what the file is called, the dataframe variable name that gets assigned will always be `data`.

Comment: @JAW, this does what I interpreted you to want, to save the data in a file with a given name (here "so.Rdata") with a given variable name (here, "x"). If you want something else, you need to clarify.

Comment: So every time I try to load a different data file with a different file name, it will always assign the dataframe variable name `data` which will overwrite the previously loaded file.  I need to load multiple unique files and end up with each dataframe assigned its own unique variable name.

Comment: @JAW: Really? On my system it names it whatever the "Quandl_FRED_Identifier" variable is.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I think this does what is needed, but I do think the explanation isn't clear. Perhaps you can make the function more generic? And the answer doesn't start out well saying that you don't need assign, when actually, you do. I also think you forgot to remove the first argument (dataID) from the save function; it's saving it now using both names.

Comment: @JAW: do you want the filename and the variable name to always be the same? That's an easy fix.

Comment: Hi Aaron, sorry but I'm not sure I'm seeing your edit.  I thought I was replying to Rui's edit.  Anyway, if you modified the code I don't think I'm seeing it.  Using the code I'm seeing when I reload the data file it always assigns the variable name `data` to the dataframe, no matter what the file name is.  BTW, what I really want to do is use the `assigned_name` for both the file name AND for the variable name assigned to the dataframe.  The `Quandl_FRED_Identifier' is often not human reader friendly.

Comment: Yeah, when I reload the file `so.Rdata` I get the correct dataframe but it's given the variable name `data`.

Comment: I didn't edit, I just suggested it in the comment. You seem open tome editing it though, so I'll do so now.

Comment: If you can tell me how to capture an image of my Rstudio environment pane I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

If I was to do this, I would separate it into three functions. The first reads in your data, however you do that. The second one saves a single R variable in an Rdata file with a new variable name, and the default filename is that variable name. The third one puts them together to read the data and save it with a new name, using the default of the filename being the name.

```
readQuandl <- function(dataID, dir="FRED") {
    Quandl.api_key("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    Quandl(file.path(dir, dataID))
}

saveAs <- function(x, name, file=paste0(name,".RData")) {
    assign(name, x)
    save(list=name, file=file)
}

saveQuandlAs <- function(dataID, name) {
    x <- readQuandl(dataID)
    saveAs(x, name)
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner. BTW, I would use the extension `RData` not `Rdata` like in the question.

Comment: OK, my apologies to everyone.  I didn't take a close enough look at Ruis' modified edit.  The following code does exactly what I want:

Comment: `retrieve_FRED_data_mod <-
  function(dataID = Quandl_FRED_Identifier, filename = assigned_name) {
    require(Quandl)
    Quandl.api_key("BXoUVBgpAJ1eQ79yjGky")
    data <- Quandl(paste(c("FRED/", dataID), collapse = ""))
    assign(filename, data)
    save(list = filename, file = paste0(filename, ".Rdata"))
    return(get(filename))
  }`

Comment: OK, that was a mess, sorry.  Will try to do a new edit.